# Date within last week show day of the week, else show date

Tags: android, date

I must be using the wrong keywords, because I think this can't be too hard. But somehow I didn't manage to find it. Often you see in for example your incoming mail that the mail from last week just says that it came in Monday or Tuesday. Older mails show the actual date.

Is there anybody who can tell me how I get from a saved date the day of the week and how can I check if it is within the last 6 days?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could check if the difference from the saved date time and current date time is under 604800000 (number of miliseconds in a week).